# How to stop program execution in console in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: console, rust, visual-studio-code, rust-cargo

I have configured tasks.json to build and launch my console application:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cargo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["run"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

It is running and calculating, but I can't stop it without Windows Task Manager. I tried right clicking and pressing **Stop Code Run**, but it doesn't help. Is there any support for running Rust programs so that I have regular start and stop buttons as in any modern IDE?